# Can I password protect a specific ms sql database view?

Tags: sql-server, security

I have an MS SQL database with a View that contains sensitive data in one column. Typically, users will consume this View in Power BI. As additional security, is it possible to password protect  the database View?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Data Masking would work in this case, , so when the view is queried from the moment you add the mask command, the end user would get four xxxx's in the result set, unless they were sysadmin or were granted UNMASK permissions.
In SQL 2019 and below, UNMASK is all masked columns or nothing, in SQL2022 , you can grant unmask on individual tables.

```
--DROP VIEW [dbo].[vwBaseTable]
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[BaseTable]') AND name = 'SensitiveColumn' ) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseTable] ALTER column [SensitiveColumn] add masked with 
(function='default()');
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwBaseTable] AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BaseTable]
--optional 
GRANT UNMASK TO [mydomain\EndUsers];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dynamic Data Masking is a very interesting approach, thank you.